# Spring Boot is not setting the @Value property in Jersey's ResourceConfig class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

why is my port member 0 in my Jersey ResourceConfig class at runtime?

Application.property file:

```
#web server
server.port=9000
```

JerseyConfig file:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath(Pathes.APPLICATION_PATH)
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int port;

    public JerseyConfig() {
        final BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:" + port);
        beanConfig.setBasePath(Pathes.APPLICATION_PATH);
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage(myPackages);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);

        register(ApiListingResource.class);
        register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
    }
}
```

Thank's for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-jersey

Comment: Can you share how your properties are registered in the xml?

Comment: In spring boot there is no XML config file. I am using the application.properties file, which is loaded at Startup by spring boot itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using port in constructor, before it's initialized by Spring container. You can't do this with Spring.

Do constructor injection instead:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath(Pathes.APPLICATION_PATH)
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JerseyConfig(@Value("${server.port}") int port) {
        final BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:" + port);
        beanConfig.setBasePath(Pathes.APPLICATION_PATH);
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage(myPackages);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);

        register(ApiListingResource.class);
        register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
    }
}
```